# When looking at the variance of a function of a r.v. $X$ (say continuous), can you use $Var(g(X)) = E(g(X)^2) - E^2(g(X))$, and then use integration?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, variance

I'll illustrate this question with an example:

Suppose $X$~Uniform[0,1] and I wish to determine $Var$($X\cos \left(X\right)$). Can I say that this is equal to $E\left(X^{2}\cos ^{2}\left(X\right)\right)-E^{2}\left(X\cos \left(X\right)\right)$ and evaluate these via the integrals $$
E^2\left(X\cos \left(X\right)\right) = \left(∫_0^1 {x\cos \left(x\right)}dx\,\right)^2
$$
and $$E\left(X^2\cos ^2\left(X\right)\right) = ∫_0^1 {x^2\cos ^2\left(x\right)}dx\, 
$$
and combine them together \left(given that these both are easily evaluated\right)?

Comment: Why not? Which is your doubt?

Comment: Why could you not? This is the definition of the variance of $Y\stackrel{\rm def}{=}g(X)$.

Comment: I guess there shouldn't be any doubt, but normally this is tough to evaluate if $$ g(X) = e^{X^{2}} $$ say. But then I guess Delta method is the next best thing

Comment: I'm not sure why this got down-voted as it's a perfectly acceptable question. I up-voted to compensate.

Comment: Thanks Remy! I understand it may seem trivial but the context of the question lies actually on a problem on simulation of random variables on R and Monte-Carlo estimators, so it is more about whether it is easier to evaluate this directly vs. via approximations such as the Delta method. Perhaps I should have clarified this.